# how to use jquery validation on specific fields only

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In my form I have 4 fields when I'm using jquery validation on form id by default it validates all the fields. I want validation on 1 mandatory field only.

My jquery is as below

jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
jQuery("#add-color-form").validate(    
{    
    rules: {
        color_name: {      
            required:true,
            maxlength: 20
        },
       
    },    
    messages: {
        color_name: {
            required: "Please enter color name",
            maxlength: "Not more than 20 characters"
        
        },
       
    }
}
);
```

}

**Still it validates all the fields while I want validation only on 1 field**

## add-color-form is my form id

Comment: can you post your html please?

Comment: I have solved it

using required in class

<input type="box" class="required" />

use required for specific mandatory fields only and its works.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to tell from the code you've supplied, make sure your inputs dont have a 'required' class and maybe bet one of the examples working first, then adjust that?